# changing fillStyle at the same time as the background color

Tags: jquery, arrays, html, canvas

I've been working on animating the background of my website and I have a visualizer going behind it, so I've made two lists with the colors they should have at the same time:

```
var frenzyModeColors = ["#BC49FF", "#574FFF", "#47FFF2", "#3AFF3D", "#9FFF4C", "#EFFF49", "#FF8A54", "#FF4C4C"];
var frenzyModeVisualizerColors = ["#FF6B83", "#FF8C3F", "#3D81FF", "#5BD3FF", "#FF962D", "#FF0004", "#FF4300", "#D8FF4F"];
```

but for some reason, the visualizer is just going crazy and switches color constantly instead of taking one colour and making a smooth transition between the current one and the new one

here's the code I have:

```
//frenzy mode background
function frenzyModeBG() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frenzyModeBG);
    if (frenzyMode == 1) {
        $("#BGFrenzy").css("opacity", 1);
        $("#visualizer").css("opacity", 1);
        $("#BGFrenzy").animate({ backgroundColor : randomRgb() }, 2500);
        ctx.fillStyle = frenzyModeVisualizerColors[BGcolor];
    }
    else {
        $("#BGFrenzy").css("opacity", 0);
        $("#visualizer").css("opacity", 0.1);
    }
};
```

**[here's the website](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpZjFJaDhTQlRfdTg/)**
(go into the option tab of the media player and activate frenzy mode to see the issue)

I've tried doing this instead:

```
$("#BGFrenzy").animate({ backgroundColor : randomRgb() }, 2500, function(){
    ctx.fillStyle = frenzyModeVisualizerColors[BGcolor];
});
```

but it's still not working like it's supposed to

I'm almost positive it's because of `window.requestAnimationFrame(frenzyModeBG);`, and if that's the case, is there any other easy ways to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, I've replace
`window.requestAnimationFrame(frenzyModeBG);`
with
`window.setInterval(function(){ frenzyModeBG() }, 7500);`